# how to use alternate content for <video> element

Tags: php

I mean what should i do so as not to display video files missing in a database row? I am new to php and this is my code.

```
<video width="100%" controls preload="auto">
 <source src="postfiles/<?php echo $res['file']; ?>" 
   type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
 <source src="postfiles/<?php echo $res['file']; ?>"
   type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
</video>
```

Comment: Any `<img>` or `<p>` could be placeholder. Use [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) for the database result and/or [`file_exists`](http://php.net/file_exists) to verify `if` the source url should be output (if that's your question).

Answer (score 1):

The contents of [the `<video>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) can be used as fallbacks in the case of no support or no content. Just as you have a second video codec in case of missing support for the first one, you can also have image or text in case there's no support for video at all, or no video to play. Perhaps something like this:

```
<video width="100%" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="postfiles/<?=$res['file']?>" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
    <source src="postfiles/<?=$res['file']?>" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <p class="error">No video found</p>
</video>
```

Or if you want to prevent the client from even trying to download videos that don't exist:

```
<video width="100%" controls preload="auto">
<?php if (!empty($res["file"])):?>
    <source src="postfiles/<?=$res['file']?>" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
    <source src="postfiles/<?=$res['file']?>" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <p>No browser support for videos</p>
<?php else:?>
    <p class="error">No video found</p>
<?php endif;?>
</video>
```

Comment: so what is the correct method to display videos from database while at the same time hide any broken video layout for the videos that don't exist in database.